# maven install to .m2 AND another folder

Tags: java, maven

I have a very large number of project that I'm migrating to maven... but i have several restrictions.

One of those is to leave the results of the builds in a certain folder.

I'm trying to make maven install the project artifacts to the local repository (.m2 as usual, because the have dependencies from one to another) and also put the jars/wars/ears files into the custom folder I refered before.

I've already used this:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <directory>${basedir}/../../target/</directory>
        <plugins>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The proyect consist in several .ear and .jar, we used to run many ant's to get those files generated in certain folder.

I'm trying to put those files in that folder from maven, so I have the exact same code i show here in every pom, but when i run maven, all but the last one is deposited in the folder (because every pom cleans that folder i supose)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish; maven package will assemble the artifact and put it into target folder, mvn install will copy this artifact to ~/.m2/... I don't know if there's a maven plugin that will copy this artifact somewhere else out of the box or you can easily write one yourself. What is being deleted?

Comment: You're right, I'm going to edit again the question. Anyway, the proyect consist in several .ear and .jar, and they used to run many ant's to get those files generated in certain folder. I'm trying to put those files in that folder from maven, so I have the exact same code i show here in every pom,  but when i run maven, all but the last one is deposited in the folder (because every pom cleans that folder i supose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only copy packages to other path, you can use [`maven-antrun-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to do this.

You can configure the plugin something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>config</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <copy todir="${the.custom.folder}" overwrite="true">
                        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}" includes="**/*.jar **/*.ear" />
                    </copy>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also look at some artifact repository, such as [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) or [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).

Comment: I I'm aware of the ant plugin, but what I 'm trying to accomplish is migrate from ant to Maven. However , I start to believe Maven alone can't do what I 'm trying to do , so I'm going to check this as a correct answer .

Comment: @chomsky as you are migrating now, consider using gradle. It is less "standardized" than maven, then will give you more flexibility. See a good comparison here: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/why-build-your-java-projects-with-gradle/240168608

Comment: This is for an insurance company, so their's technologies migration is slow. Thanks anyway for the advice, i'll check it later